# How to specify a list of unknown size in a loop

Tags: python

I have code that supposedly is able to extract the largest number of an integer list. If the size of the list is unknown, it could be 5 numbers or 30 numbers, how would I specify the it in the if loop?

```
f = 3,2,5,9,13,1,...
for loop in (f):
    x = f[0]
    if(x < f[0] or x < f[1] or x < f[2] or x < f[3] or x < f[4] or x < f[5] or ...):
        x = f[0+1]
```

Comment: list are iteables, for you can do for x in your_list. You say size of the list is unknown, but it is NOT unknown. list are finites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your misunderstanding is.

You need to keep track of the largest:

```
largest = f[0]
for loop in f:
    if loop > largest:
        largest = loop
```

There is a nice builtin function [**`max`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) which is very flexible.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to use is `max`. Supplied with an iterable `max` will return the item with greatest value.

```py
>>> f = 3,2,5,9,13,1
>>> max(f)
13
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify size. Just sort the list and get the last, largest number as shown below.

```
f.sort()
print("Largest number is:", f[-1])
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: sort complexity is higher than a max complexity. It's not optimized

Comment: Additionally to the runtime complexity, this modifies the list, which might be also undesirable. In the example, it's also specified as a tuple, which is immutable. There's the [**`sorted`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function which returns a sorted list of elements from whatever iterable you pass to it.

Comment: Thanks much Timothee and Peter for your comments. Learnt new things. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do YOUR function max then

```
def get_max(int_list):
    best_max = False
    for value in int_list:
        if best_max == False or best_max < value:
            best_max = value
    return best_max


int_list = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print ( get_max(int_list) )
```

You can see it return False if array is empty.
Why do not use max(f) function ?

Comment: I cannot use max(f), guidelines require that I only use certain commands. If I could use max(f), I would

Comment: Okay no problem :D

Answer (score -1):

I think you're trying to define some sort of sort algorithm? You're looking to compare an entry in a list to all the entries previous in the list, right? You can subset the list with `list.index()` and compare against that:

```
f = 3,2,5,9,13,1,...
for loop in (f):
    listy= f[0:f.index(loop)] # subset list up to current element
                              # loop is not a reserved word, but 
                              # I still wouldn't use it in this sense
    for y in listy:           # iterate through subset
        if loop < y:          # check conditional
            loop = f[f.index(loop)+1] # move up one element in the list
```

What you'll discover is that the output here, if the conditional evaluates to `True`, will replace the next element in the list. It will not move it forward. Using the provided `f`, it would end up with `[3,2,2,2,2,2,2...]` because the list is modifying itself inplace. You need to bring in more list(s) and go from there.